# How to load data from RDBMS to Tinkergraph using Gremlin using java code?

Tags: java, gremlin, rdbms, tinkerpop3

I need to load data from RDBMS to Tinkergraph using Gremlin using java code.

Ex: Select name,age from employee. There are 1000 rows. How to construct tinkergraph for such data?

Tried going through content available online but did not get to load data from rdbms table to graph for hundreds of thousands of rows

Comment: SO did not let me edit for lack of capacity, so upvoted to 0. Question can be understood by TinkerPop experts, but not by the general audience.

Answer (score 0):

This doc linked below discusses the main points of converting from a traditional, tabular RDBMS schema into a graph model and writing data into a TinkerPop-compatible datastore using Grmelin:

https://aws-samples.github.io/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/src/converting-to-graph/